# ANTLR v4: How do I capture an arbitrary trimmed string to the end of line/file after a certain token?

Tags: antlr4

For curiosity's sake I'm learning ANTLR, in particular, 4 and I'm trying to create a simple grammar. I chose NES (Nintentdo Entertainment System) Game Genie files the very first attempt. Let's say, here is a sample Game Genie file for Jurassic Park found somewhere in Internet:

```
GZUXXKVS        Infinite ammo on pick-up
PAVPAGZE        More bullets picked up from small dinosaurs
PAVPAGZA        Fewer bullets picked up from small dinosaurs
GZEULOVK        Infinite lives--1st 2 Levels only
ATVGZOSA        Immune to most attacks
VEXASASA + VEUAXASA     3-ball bolas picked up
NEXASASA + NEUAXASA     Explosive multi-shots
```

And here is a grammar I'm working on.

```
grammar NesGameGenie;

all: lines EOF;

lines: (anyLine? EOL+)* anyLine?;

anyLine: codeLine;

codeLine: code;
code: CODE (PLUS? CODE)*;

CODE: SHORT_CODE | LONG_CODE;
fragment SHORT_CODE: FF FF FF FF FF FF;
fragment LONG_CODE: FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF;
fragment FF: [APZLGITYEOXUKSVN];

COMMENT: COMMENT_START NOEOL -> skip;
COMMENT_START: [#;];

EOL: '\r'? '\n';
PLUS: '+';
WS: [ \t]+ -> skip;
fragment NOEOL: ~[\r\n]*;
```

Well it's ridiculously short and easy, but it still has two issues I can see:

- The cheats descriptions cause recognition errors like `line 1:16 token recognition error at: 'In'` because there is no a description rule provided to the grammar.
- Adding the `#` symbol to the description will probably cause ignore the rest to the end of line. At least, `AAAAAA Player #1 ammo` only reports `Player` and `#1 ammo` is unfortunately parsed as a comment, but I think it could be fixed once the description rule is introduced.

My previous attempts to add the description rule caused a lot of various errors, and I've found a non-error but still not a good solution:

```
...
codeLine: code description?;
...
description: PRINTABLE+;
...
PRINTABLE: [\u0020-\uFFFE];
...
```

Unfortunately every character is parsed as a single `PRINTABLE`, and what I'm looking for is a `description` rule to match arbirtrary text until the end of line (or file) including whitespaces, but trimmed on left and right. If I add `+` to the end of the `PRINTABLE`, the whole document is considered invalid. I guess that `PRINTABLE` might be safely inlined to the `description` rule somehow, but `description: ('\u0020' .. '\uFFFE')+;` captures way more.

How should the `description` rule be declared to let it capture all characters to the end of line right after the codes, but trimming whitespaces (`[ \t]`) on both left and right only? Simply speaking, I would have a grammar that would parse into something like (including the `#` character not parsing it as a comment):

```
code=..., description="Infinite ammo on pick-up"
code=..., description="More bullets picked up from small dinosaurs"
code=..., description="Fewer bullets picked up from small dinosaurs"
code=..., description="Infinite lives--1st 2 Levels only"
code=..., description="Immune to most attacks"
code=..., description="3-ball bolas picked up"
code=..., description="Explosive multi-shots"
```

One more note, I'm using:

- IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1.1 CE
- IJ plugin: ANTLR v4 grammar plugin 1.8.1
- IJ plugin: ANTLRWorks 1.3.1

Comment: The question is good but because of the NES I would have given it +2 ! :)

Comment: @cantSleepNow NES is awesome. :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quite easy actually, just use lexer modes. Once you hit certain tokens, change the mode.

Here is the lexer grammar, parser is easy based on that (filename is `NesGameGenieLexer.g4`):

```
lexer grammar NesGameGenieLexer;

CODE: [A-Z]+;

WS : [ ]+ -> skip, mode(COMMENT_MODE);

mode COMMENT_MODE;
PLUS: '+' (' ')* -> mode(DEFAULT_MODE);
fragment ANY_CHAR: [a-zA-Z_/0-9=.\-\\ ];
COMMENT: ANY_CHAR+;
NEWLINE: [\r\n] -> skip, mode(DEFAULT_MODE);
```

I've assumed that `+` can't be in comments. If you use ANTLRWorks lexer debugger you can see all the token types and token modes nicely highlighted.

And here is the parser grammar (filename is `NesGameGenieParser.g4`):

```
parser grammar NesGameGenieParser;

options {
  tokenVocab=NesGameGenieLexer;
}

file: line+;

line : code comment
     | code PLUS code comment;

code: CODE;

comment: COMMENT;
```

Here I've assumed that `CODE` is just set of chars before `PLUS` but obviously that's very easy to change :)

Comment: I shall check it as soon as I can! Thank you so far!

Comment: That was a crazy night challenge to me, but it seems to work. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/a/40167472/166589 -- a solution based on your idea. I don't know if it's well-written, but it also fixes the `+` character problem, fixes the leading whitespaces issue, allows multiple codes and optional description (and maybe something else I can't recall now). The text trimming hack looks awful, but I have no idea how to work around it or simplify more. Thank you for giving the idea!

Answer (score 0):

Spending the whole sleepless night and having much less time to sleep, I seem to have managed to write the lexer and parser grammars. No need to explain much, see the comments in the source code, so in short:

The lexer:

```
lexer grammar NesGameGenieLexer;

COMMENT: [#;] ~[\r\n]+ [\r\n]+ -> skip;

CODE: (SHORT_CODE | LONG_CODE) -> mode(CODE_FOUND_MODE);
fragment SHORT_CODE: FF FF FF FF FF FF;
fragment LONG_CODE: FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF;
fragment FF: [APZLGITYEOXUKSVN];
WS: [\t ]+ -> skip;

mode CODE_FOUND_MODE;
PLUS: [\t ]* '+' [\t ]* -> mode(DEFAULT_MODE);
// Skip inline whitespaces and switch to the description detection mode.
DESCRIPTION_LEFT_DELIMITER: [\t ]+ -> skip, mode(DESCRIPTION_FOUND_MODE);
NEW_LINE_IN_CODE_FOUND_MODE: [\r\n]+ -> skip, mode(DEFAULT_MODE);

mode DESCRIPTION_FOUND_MODE;
// Greedily grab all non-CRLF characters and ignore trailing spaces - this is a trimming operation equivalent, I guess.
DESCRIPTION: ~[\r\n]*~[\r\n\t ]+;
// But then terminate the line and switch to the code detection mode.
// This operation is probably required because the `DESCRIPTION: ... -> mode(CODE_FOUND_MODE)` seems not working
NEW_LINE_IN_DESCRIPTION_FOUND_MODE: [\r\n]+ -> skip, mode(DEFAULT_MODE);
```

The parser:

```
parser grammar NesGameGenieParser;

options {
    tokenVocab = NesGameGenieLexer;
}

file
    : line+
    ;

line
    : code description?
    | code (PLUS code)* description?
    ;

code
    : CODE
    ;

description
    : DESCRIPTION
    ;
```

It is looks much more complicated than I thought it should work, but it seems to work exactly the way I want. Also, I'm not sure if the grammars above are really well-written and idiomatic. Thanks to @cantSleepNow for giving the modes idea.